# Can I use different DNS server depending on website I'm going to visit?

Tags: dns

I've been working in an company where there is an DNS server which could resolve our company network's address. But problems comes when I wanna use Google because it's blocked in China.
I have VPN to solve this problem but it's too slow.So I choose to use another DNS server and it works.
But if I use that DNS server,I could not visit my company's website. If I use my company's DNS server, I could not visit Google.
Is there any way that I could have my computer use company's DNS server while visiting company's website and use the other DNS server while visiting google,twitter,etc?

Note that IP addresses is always changing,so hosts doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [dnsmasq](http://dnsmasq.org), where you can this configuration using the parameter `--server`:

`--server=/google.com/1.2.3.4`: this will send all *.google.com queries to server 1.2.3.4